# How can I manipulate the clicked button inside array map without affecting other ones?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got API data and used it with the `map` method. Note that for each item of `data`, I have an `AddButton` component. I want to click the button that is inside `map` and change the text of the clicked one, without effecting the others, but this results in changing all buttons. How can I manipulate just the clicked one?

```
{data.map((values) =>
    <>
        <Items >
            <h5>Title: {values.title}</h5>
            <h2 >Price: {values.price}</h2>
            <img src={values.image} alt=""
                width="100"
                height="60" />
            <Addbutton  onClick={() => {
                Added();
            }}>
            </Addbutton>
        </Items>
    </>
)}
```

Comment: Make each item its own component with its own state and handle the click inside there.

Comment: How are you specifying the click behavior?

Comment: Your fragment markup (`< />`) isn't needed, by the way. You only need that if you're returning multiple elements.

Comment: @kelly that is an item component although it's been pluralised for some reason. OP you may want to consider changing that to `<Item>` to save on the confusion. And you either need to pass in an id to the `added` function, or have the function pick up the id from the element that fired the click event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event, or at least the event target, so you can reference that.

```
{data.map(values =>
  <Items>
      ...

      <Addbutton onClick={event => Added(event.currentTarget)} />
  </Items>
)}
```

Then your function accepts `currentTarget` as an element:

```
const Added = element => { // do stuff with element }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to identify which item your button belongs to, and you can do that by adding an id property to the data. Here I've added it to the mock data I'm passing into the component.

On each iteration of `map` create a new `Item` passing down an id, a reference to the function that will be called when the button is clicked, and a new property called `added`. This will either be set to the item's property if it exists, or false.

When `handleClick` is called it makes a copy of the items state, looks for the object in the array with a matching id, adds the `added` property setting it to true, and then updates the items state. When that happens the component re-renders with the new state, and the button will change when the `added` property is `true`.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {
  
  const [items, setItems] = useState(data);
  
  function handleClick(id) {
    const copy = [...items];
    const index = copy.findIndex(item => item.id === +id);
    copy[index].added = true;
    setItems(copy);
  }

  return (
    <main>
      {items.map(item => {
        return (
          <Item
            key={item.id}
            added={item.added || false}
            handleClick={handleClick}
            {...item}
          />
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );
}

function Item(props) {

  const {
    id,
    added,
    title,
    price,
    handleClick
  } = props;
  
  return (
    <section className="item">
      <p className="title">{title}</p>
      <p className="price">{price}</p>
      <Add
        added={added}
        id={id}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
    </section>
  );

}

function Add({ added, id, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <button
      className="add"
      onClick={() => handleClick(id)}
      disabled={added}
    >{added ? 'Added item' : 'Add item'}
    </button>
  );
}

const data = [{id: 1, title: 'Car', price: 65000},{id: 2, title: 'Elephant', price: 620000},{id: 3, title: 'Wax Museum', price: 25000000}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.item { background-color: #dcFecc; margin: 0.25em 0.4em; padding: 0.25em; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; }
.title { font-weight: 600; color: blue; }
.price { color: red; }
.add:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```